# How to get generalization of term. Prolog

Tags: prolog

For example - I have some terms:

```
moves(1, [1]).
moves(1, [2]).
moves(1, [3]).
```

How can I get next term?

```
moves(1, [1,2,3]).
```

---

```
% I have
    moves(1, [1]).
    moves(1, [2]).
    moves(1, [3]).

% I need to write some predicate which
    transform_moves :- 
        % ...
        % ...
        assert(moves(Pos, Arr)),

        % moves(1, [1,2,3]).
```

Comment: What do you mean with "get"? Do you want to construct the last term from the previous three?

Comment: Look to question now. I update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Program:

```
:- dynamic moves/2.

moves(1, [1]).
moves(1, [2]).
moves(1, [3]).

transform_moves(Pos) :- 
    findall(Y, moves(Pos, [Y]), L), 
    retractall(moves(Pos, _)),
    assert(moves(Pos, L)).
```

Call:

```
?- transform_moves(1).
```